# Setting the export report name in Show-Listview in SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions

I wondered if it's possible to set the report name when exporting to something specific when using Show-ListView in SPE?

Looking at the docs I can't see any params for this but maybe I've missed something: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/show-listview.

The only thing that looked to maybe work was the -ViewName param. I tried it like so but I still just get a report called 'report-yyyy-mm-dd_id.xlsx':

```
Show-ListView @props -Property @{Label="Id"; Expression={$_.Id} },
                @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName} },
                @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.ItemPath} } -ViewName "test-report"
```

For reference we are using Sitecore 9.3 with SPE 6.0 but I can't see any option for this in 6.3 either.

Comment: Have you tried InfoDescription and Title? Have a look at any of the ootb reports for a more complete example.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelWest , I am using Title, InfoTitle, InfoDescription already but these just show in the report window but don't seem to affect the actual download filename. I've checked over every single report in 6.3 and all of them seem to be setting these values too but I can't see any setting the file name. Is there one you can think of that does?

Comment: The output formats currently have no configuration exposed through the command. You could add your own custom output action and show only in your reports. This however would require more work on your part.